# How to retrieve an image converted to byte array from sqlite db and place it in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm stuck in problem. It's one of my first android apps and I don't know how to overcome this thing. My problem is i have a SQLite database in which I am saving an image converted to byte array and some more data but when I am retrieving that data and want to show in RecyclerView then image is not showing up in RecyclerView list. Other data is  displayed properly, but image field is empty. Does anyone know what is wrong in my code?

That's how I'm trying to set a list item in adapter (onBindViewHolder):

```
        byte[] image = selectedGame.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        gameItemView.imageGame.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It's my GameListActivity where I fill list with gamesData:

```
        gamesRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gamesRecyclerView);
        gamesData = new ArrayList<>();
        gamesAdapter = new GamesAdapter(gamesData);
        ((GamesAdapter) gamesAdapter).setGamesActivity(this);


        Cursor cursor = db.getGames();
        gamesData.clear();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No games in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                gamesData.add(new Game(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameTitle")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameGenre")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("year")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameDescription")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gamePC")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gamePS3")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gamePS4")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameXONE")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameX360")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameNINTENDO")),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("likesCount")),
                        cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"))
                ));
            }

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    gamesRecyclerView.setAdapter(gamesAdapter);
    gamesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Here I'm adding a game to database (that's interesting that when I'm trying to get all games after adding some game then it prints out wrong array of bytes):

```
 btnAddYourGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    byte[] gameImage = imageViewToByte(image);
                    System.out.println(gameImage.length);
                    Boolean checkGame = openHelper.checkIfGameExists(title);
                        if (checkGame == true) {
                            openHelper.addGame(title, genre, year, description, pcAvailable, ps3Available, ps4Available, x360Available, xoneAvailable, nintendoAvailable, gameImage);
                            Cursor cursor = openHelper.getGames();
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                System.out.println(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image")).length);
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.action_game_add_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.action_game_add_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Much to much code. Too many questions. . Nobody likes to go to all that code. Start with retrieving the byte array from the database. The same amount of bytes as you put in?

Comment: Well. I checked this and that's where the problem is. When im adding a game with image to database, image after converting has 181482 bytes and when im trying to load this game to the list - it has only 11 bytes. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You are not saving an image to the database. `I am saving an image converted to byte array` So you are saving a byte array to the database. How many bytes in that byte array? And how many bytes in the array if you extract it from the database? That the byte array contains bytes for an image is irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: I checked this and when Im trying to add a game to database, the array has something about 181k bytes, but when im trying to get it from the cursor (getBlob.length) it has only 11 bytes

Comment: Please remove all code. Then post only code to put a byte array in the database. Then add code to retrieve the array. Focus on your problem.

Comment: I've just updated my question

Comment: Still to much code. Here you extract the array from the database. `cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"))`. What do you get here? It should be the byte arry. You did not post the Game class so we do not know how you handle the blob. I would think `byte myarray[] =cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"))` would better demonstrate the retrievel of the array.

Comment: `byte[] image= selectedGame.getImage();` Well... What are you doing there? You are not showing code. And could it have been `byte[] image = =cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));` ?

Comment: `openHelper.addGame()`. You did not post code for that function. So we still do not know how you put a byte array in your database. Forget about your game and game clasesses. Just try to put a byte array in a blob and extract it. Post only that code. Focus on your problem.

Comment: Okay, problem solved. I've got to rewrite addGame function to execute insert command with bindings. Then it works properly. Appreciate your effort